# Apollo - nothing happens unless there's 2 line breaks...?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I've certainly never encountered this one before.

I'm using Apollo with React, and using `apollo-link-state` to manage local state. If I include 2 lines before `writeQuery` in my resolver, everything works perfectly:

```
const openModal = (_, { operation, dataType }, { cache }) => {
  let { currentModal } = cache.readQuery({
    query: GET_MODAL_DATA
  });

  currentModal.operation = operation;
  currentModal.dataType = dataType;
  currentModal.isVisible = true;
  // this one
  // and this one
  cache.writeQuery({
    query: GET_MODAL_DATA,
    data: { currentModal }
  })

  return null;
}
```

Remove the second line break ("// and this one"), and nothing happens at all. That sounds insane, but I've tested this over and over.

Is this something anyone's encountered before? I'd love to include more detail, but I'm not even really sure what to add. So strange.

Comment: Are you getting any error after removing these lines?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all. Everything works just as if the openModal function hadn't been called.